# Not able to start and stop services through subprocess in python

Tags: python

I am not able to start and stop services in python through subprocee. getting error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "subProcessExample.py", line 3, in <module>
p = Popen(["C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat8.0/bin", service, "stop"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__  
   errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child 
 startupinfo) 
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: Please post the traceback more readably. Put it in a code block so the lines won't be wrapped.

Comment: The error message seems to be clear: you're trying to run a program that you don't have appropriate privileges for. You need to be `root` to stop and start services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my error as follows

1.I changed the name of the service with extension .exe
2.I run cmd as administrator

Here is my code to start and stop services

```
# To stop service
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
path = "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.0/bin/"
service = "Tomcat8.exe"
def startService(service, path):
 p = Popen([path+service, "start"])
 stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
 if(p.poll() == 0):
     print "SUCCESS"
 else:
    print "Failed to start"
startService(service, path)

#To stop service replace "start" with "stop"
```